# How to spread light?

Tags: lighting

I am looking to film near a window. I was wondering if there was a certain material that can take the sun light source and spread it evenly and wider. I find that a diffuser it isn't enough is there another type of material that would spread and expand it even?

Comment: Is the window in shot?

Comment: Define "isn't enough"--what specific issue are you having? Light level? Color? Contrast?

Answer (score 1):

A prism would separate the light into a spectrum, which probably isn't what you want. If the window isn't visible in your shot, you could use what's sometimes called a ***silk***, which is more often made of muslin or other semi-translucent material.

Comment: A "silk" (whatever its actual fiber composition) is exactly a "diffuser" which armoose said "isn't enough".

Comment: @RichardCrowley  Right. But he didn't say what he used as a diffuser and given the lack of other details it certainly bears suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention: size/area, permanent/temporary, budget, etc. etc.  So, in the absense of any practical constraints, letting my imagination run wild....

I would investigate hanging a row of round acrylic ("Plexiglas") rods like a curtain which would serve rather like a big amorphous "Fresnel lens".

Else, you could use the traditional "brute-force" method used by big-budget production companies:

1. **Giant lamps** outside the window focused through the opening. They commonly use expensive (and very bright) HMI lights for "punching through" sunlight levels.
2. **Big reflectors** that catch extra sunlight and reflect it in through the window.  Metalized reflective fabric stretched on a big frame

[image: HMI light augmenting sunlight through window.]

[image: Reflectors to augment/redirect sunlight]

Answer (score 0):

How about a bedsheet over the outside of the window?  Possibly along with some correcting gel to bring the color temperature closer to any other sources you want to use inside?